# subclassing the builtin enumerate in python

Tags: python, built-in, enumerate

Consider the code below. I am trying to subclass the builtin `enumerate` so that it prints a line for every turn of the for loop. The code seems to be working, which is surprising, because I have never called `super().__init__(x)`. So, what is happening here? Who is initializing the base class `enumerate` the right way? Is there some magic from the `__new__` method happening here?

```
class myenum(enumerate):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x_   = x
        self.len_ = len(x)
        
    def __next__(self):
        out = super().__next__()
        print(f'Doing {out[0]} of {self.len_}')
        return out

for ictr, key in myenum(['a','b','c','d','e']):
    print('Working...')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__init__` method is always optional. All initialization of an instance can always be done purely in the `__new__` method, which is the case for the `enumerate` class, whose `__new__` method is defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/enumobject.c#L43) in the `enum_new_impl` function, where you can see that the `iterable` argument is stored as the attribute `en_sit` of the returning object `en`, of the struct type `enumobject`:

```
static PyObject *
enum_new_impl(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *iterable, PyObject *start)
{
    enumobject *en;

    ...

    en->en_sit = PyObject_GetIter(iterable);

    ...

    return (PyObject *)en;
}
```

Comment: That being said, I strongly suspect that the lack of `__init__` is a CPython implementation detail, not actually a rule of Python. So other implementations are likely free to reject the OP's code, since I seriously doubt the Python developers were thinking about subclassing when they wrote `enumerate`.